# Stripping Comma From Numbers in Scrapy

Tags: python, string, scrapy

So, i'm working on a school project to pull some data using Scrapy to pull data into a CSV file.  The data has commas on the website, but I want to strip the comma from the numbers, as some rows i'm pulling have three numbers and with commas, the data is all distorted.

Can see in the image below in yellow, where the comma has been stripped, but in the pinkish highlight where the commmas are still there.

[image]

It appears that in using the replace function it's working for some of the rows, but not the others.  Can't figure out where I went wrong.  Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy


class PsaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'psa'
    allowed_domains = ['psacard.com']
    start_urls = ['https://www.psacard.com/pop/t206/']

    def parse(self, response):
        rows = response.css('table.pop-grid tbody tr')
        for row in rows:
            yield {
            'name' : row.css('td')[0].css('span.t206-pop-title::text').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'variety' : row.css('td')[0].css('span.variety::text').extract_first(default='').strip(),
            'auth' : [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[3]//text()').extract()],
            'psa1': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[4]//text()').extract()],
            'psa1.5': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[5]//text()').extract()],
            'psa2': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[6]//text()').extract()],
            'psa3': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[7]//text()').extract()],
            'psa4': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[8]//text()').extract()],
            'psa5': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[9]//text()').extract()],
            'psa6': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[10]//text()').extract()],
            'psa7': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[11]//text()').extract()],
            'psa8': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[12]//text()').extract()],
            'psa9': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[13]//text()').extract()],
            'psa10': [x.strip().replace(',','') for x in row.xpath('td[14]//text()').extract()],
            }
```

Comment: You are on the right path or using `replace()` but you also have to replace the `-` and not only the commas. If you want more help please post a minimal and functional code example :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure about commas? I think you have problem with dashes here. Try something like this:

```
def parse(self, response):
    def strip_second(sel, xpath):
        return sum([int(x.strip().replace(',', '')) for x in sel.xpath(xpath).extract() if u'-' not in x])

    def strip_first(sel, css):
        return sel.css(css).get('').strip()

    rows = response.css('table.pop-grid tbody tr')
    for row in rows:
        td = row.css('td')[0]
        yield {
            'name': strip_first(td, 'span.t206-pop-title::text'),
            'variety': strip_first(td, 'span.variety::text'),
            'auth': strip_second(row, 'td[3]//text()'),
            'psa1': strip_second(row, 'td[4]//text()'),
            'psa1.5': strip_second(row, 'td[5]//text()'),
            'psa2': strip_second(row, 'td[6]//text()'),
            'psa3': strip_second(row, 'td[7]//text()'),
            'psa4': strip_second(row, 'td[8]//text()'),
            'psa5': strip_second(row, 'td[9]//text()'),
            'psa6': strip_second(row, 'td[10]//text()'),
            'psa7': strip_second(row, 'td[11]//text()'),
            'psa8': strip_second(row, 'td[12]//text()'),
            'psa9': strip_second(row, 'td[13]//text()'),
            'psa10': strip_second(row, 'td[14]//text()'),
        }
```

Example of output will be:

```
{'psa1.5': [u'0', u'0'], 'auth': [u'2'], 'psa10': [u'0'], 'psa9': [u'0', u'0'], 'psa8': [u'0', u'0', u'0'], 'name': u'Wheat, Zack', 'variety': '', 'psa4': [u'0', u'0', u'0'], 'psa5': [u'0', u'1', u'0'], 'psa6': [u'0', u'0', u'0'], 'psa7': [u'0', u'0', u'0'], 'psa1': [u'0', u'0'], 'psa2': [u'0', u'0', u'0'], 'psa3': [u'0', u'0', u'0']}
```

Comment: very cool. thanks!  i have two questions on this.  i'm still having the comma issue. it's on that first line with the totals, so it's causing some problems.  where would i put that in this code?  second, ultimately, i would like to just sum those three numbers for each category in each row....would i be able to sum before exporting?  I had planned on just taking care of this in excel, but if can do it in the code would be a lot easier..

Comment: Ok, now I got you. Check code in answer now, I've updated function `strip_second`.